access denied OS module python
Right now I am working on a project a Files manager
#delete file

import os

file_path = r"The\\path_file"

try:
    os.remove(file_path)
    print("The file has been removed")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found.")
except PermissionError:
    print("Access denied. You don't have permission to remove this file.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


I created this code because when I wrote the line it told me I had access denied, I knew it woildn't delete the file I wanted because the file was opened by another program, so i took diferente files, and got always the same problem
to understand what really was hapening I put a try execpt condition,:
try:
    os.remove(file_path)
    print("The file has been removed")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found.")
except PermissionError:
    print("Access denied. You don't have permission to remove this file.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

and once again it keeps telling me "access denied" I already used VsCode as an admistrator even CMD I keep having the same problem, I searched on stackoverflow but none of the asnwers was working

Check your path. It should be either double backslashes or a raw-string, not both.

Is there a difference between the first try/except and the second one? If not, why did you post it twice?

Do you have write permission to the folder containing the file?

@Barmar sorry my bad I put it twice to make it clear what I did to understand excatly what was the issue
